# Install hadoop on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Hadoop on Ubuntu 12.04, my system is 32 bit compatible.

I am Linux newbie. I tried [this](https://github.com/pauldix/working-with-big-data/blob/master/lesson1/steps.txt) tutorial.

I have done these steps successfully:

```
Part 1 install Hadoop:

First, install Sun JDK 6. Go to the following page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

Look for x86, agree to the license, and download the file. I did this on my laptop and copied it up to the server via scp. Once it's up there follow these installation instructions:
chmod +x jdk-6u32-linux-x86.bin
./jdk-6u32-linux-x86.bin
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
sudo mv jdk1.6.0_32 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javaws 1

# now we're ready to install hadoop. taken from https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Installing+CDH4+on+a+Single+Linux+Node+in+Pseudo-distributed+Mode

# update apt to be able to access cloudera
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/one-click-install/lucid/amd64/cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb
curl -s http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/cdh/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update

# install hadoop
sudo su
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/
```

But while I try installing 'hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo' I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo'
```

Would you please let me know what causes the problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144433/how-to-install-hadoop

Comment: Run hadoop fs -ls / is this working fine??